# Custom action logging in Magento 2 EE

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, action, logging, magento2-enterprise

I'm trying to find out **how to add custom event logging in the Magento 2 admin** to log actions taken by our employees.

One of the reasons we've upgraded to the Enterprise edition is the addition of action logs, therefore I'd like to implement custom logging events, but I have no clue how to use it. Is there anyone out there who tried to do custom logging of actions?

**Example:**

One of our sales people updated one of the supplier's information, I'd like to see who did it on the next page:

```
<domain>/admin/admin/logging/index
```

How can I implement custom action logging?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to simply add Admin Logging to a module by adding a logging.xml and declare a group and afterwards enable this group in the configuration.

`Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Admin Action Logs > Your Group Name`

*If you add a new one it will be **disabled by default***

Example of a logging.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<logging xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Logging:etc/logging.xsd">
    <groups>
        <group name="group_identifier_here">
            <label translate="true">Action Group Label here</label>
            <expected_models>
                <expected_model class="Vendor\Module\Model\Class" />
            </expected_models>
            <events>
                <event controller_action="fullcontroller_actionname_here_save" action_alias="save" />
                <event controller_action="fullcontroller_actionname_here_delete"
                       action_alias="delete" />
            </events>
        </group>
    </groups>
</logging>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was the solution! Actually quite a nice solution, I thought it'd be a lot tougher.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! is there any way we can enable our custom action Group ?

Answer (score 0):

app/code/Vendor/AdminLog/etc/logging.xml - you need to put code in  logging.xml
-Thanks