# Magento 2 EE - Need to add custom mass action in admin action log report

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-enterprise

I added the custom mass action for `invoice` and `shipment`.

[image]

Now I need to add these custom action in Admin `Action log report`

[image]

following is the screenshot of default action log report

[image]

I already tried this solution [Custom action logging in Magento 2 EE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191231/custom-action-logging-in-magento-2-ee) though it will add the Action group label in Admin action log but it will not save logs in Action log report

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share your solution, Thanks.